# Change privilege on Knex.js with OracleDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, knex.js, node-oracledb

I am trying to use knex.js with oracledb but on every query i get the following error:

```
Error: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
{
  errorNum: 28009,
  offset: 0,
  originalStack: 'Error: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER'
}
```

Here is my Knex.js config:

```
const dbconfig = {
    user:               process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password:           process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    connectString:      process.env.DB_LINK
}

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'oracledb',
    native: false,
    connection: { privilege: oracledb.SYSDBA, ...dbconfig },
    fetchAsString: [ 'number', 'clob' ],
    asyncStackTraces: true,
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 10000
})
```

Thank you in advance for any help with this matter.

Comment: try to use it like: `privilege: 'SYSDBA', ...dbconfig`  cause error says it should be `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER` - seems like `oracledb` object does not have `SYSDBA` field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, oracledb does have SYSDBA, actually you can pass it when using oracledb.getConnection({privilege: oracledb.SYSDBA}) but I don't know how to pass it to Knex.js. 

Btw I have found a solution to my problem, just added a new user to the database and stopped using sys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the use of user 'sys', I just created a new user with correct privileges and it is working fine.